# Allocation of memory, segmentation error in C

Tags: c

I have this problem I need to solve. I am given a program which is supposed to allocate memory to create an array of doubles, but something is wrong with it. Basically, main and the function create_array are broken, and I need to fix it. The solution I came up with comes up with a segmentation error and i am not sure why.

First off I decided to delete the "free(array)" in main b/c array is a pointer which does not exist in heap from my understanding.
I tried changing the function "create_array" to the following

```
void create_array(double *x, unsigned long n) {

   double *d = malloc((int)n *sizeof(double));

    if(d == NULL){
        printf("Sorry Memory Not Available. Program Terminated.\n");
        exit(1);

    }

    x=d;
    free(d);

}
```

Here is what I was provided with:

```
int main(void) {
    printf("\nProgram started...\n");
    double *array = NULL;
    int n = 20;
    create_array(array, n);

    if( array != NULL) {
        populate_array(array, n);

        // displays half of the values of the array
        for(int i = 0; i < n/2; i++){
            printf("%f\n", *array++);
        }

        // According to C standard, the program's behaviour, after the following
        // call to the function free is considered "Undefined" and needs to be
        // fixed.
        free(array);
    }

    printf("Program terminated...\n");
    return 0;
}

// THE FOLLOWING FUNCTION IS NOT PROPERLY DESINGED AND NEEDS TO BE FIXED
void create_array(double *x, unsigned long n) {
    x = malloc(n *sizeof(double));
    if(x == NULL){
        printf("Sorry Memory Not Available. Program Terminated.\n");
        exit(1);
    }
}

void populate_array(double *array, int n) {
    int i;
    for(i = 0; i < n; i++)
        array[i] = (i + 1) * 100;
}
```

When I run the code with my edit, i get segmentation error. When I run the code with no changes, it simply outputs "program started \n program terminated".

Comment: you allocated memory pointed by `d` and then you freed that mem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several errors in `create_array`. `x` is a local variable, so it will not change. Also, you `free` the memory after initialization, which in practice makes the whole function useless. Free should be done after you're done with the memory.

Here is a corrected version

```
void create_array(double **x, unsigned long n) {
    double *d = malloc((int)n *sizeof(double));

    if(d == NULL){
        printf("Sorry Memory Not Available. Program Terminated.\n");
        exit(1);
    }

    *x=d;
}
```

And then you call it like this:

```
double *p;
create_array(&p, size);
/* Do something */
free(p);
```

But, IMHO it would be better to do like this:

```
double *create_array(size_t n) {
    double *d = malloc(n*sizeof(*d));

    if(d == NULL){
        fprintf(stderr, "Sorry Memory Not Available. Program Terminated.\n");
        exit(1);
    }

    return d;
}
```

Changes:

- Returns the pointer instead of using an output parameter
- Use `size_t` instead of `unsigned long`
- Print errors to `stderr` insteadd of `stdio`
- Use `malloc(size *sizeof(<var>))` instead of `malloc(size * sizeof(<type>))`

And here is the call:

```
double *p = create_array(&p, size);
/* Do something */
free(p);
```

Comment: Why the need for `d` in `create_array`? Could just use `x`

Comment: @EdHeal There is no need. In that version I only corrected the most critical things. As you can see I wrote a better one below.

Comment: @EdHeal Besides, using an extra pointer like that can make the code easier to read by avoiding pointer to pointer. I don't see the harm of it.

Answer (score 3):

The problem is, in both code and snippet provided, the variable assigned by `malloc`'s return value lives until the function returns. So you need to use pointer-to-pointer. Moreover, in the first snippet, if you `free` the area allotted already, you can't use the space anymore.

```
void create_array(double **x, unsigned long n) {
    *x = malloc(n *sizeof(double));
    if(*x == NULL){
        printf("Sorry Memory Not Available. Program Terminated.\n");
        exit(1);
    }
}
```

In main, you can call it as `create_array(&array, n);`.

Comment: ... and `create_array(array, n);` should read `create_array(&array, n);`